# Routing to a 'sub-controller'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 'companies_controller' which is getting big as it is controlling everything. A company has a service which I need it to be set 'sub-route' of companies.

I routed my company like this:

```
resources :companies do
  member do
    get 'services/service'
  end
end
```

I use this to access my route:
services_service_company_path

I get this:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Companies
```

Any help? I'm new to Rail/Ruby so I'm not sure how to state my problem correctly.

Comment: try to run `rake routes` and check if `services_service_company_path` exists...

Comment: services_service_company GET    (/:locale)/companies/:id/services/service(.:format) companies/:id/services#service

Comment: or how to 'slave' a controller, i.e. I want that Services controller be a nested controller. Not sure how to put it in Rails terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `services` as a nested controller of companies, you can do something like:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :services
end
```

If besides the REST routes provided by resources you also need a `GET service`:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :services do
    member do
      get 'service'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It worked but my layout broke... My controller is ok but I get a page without my application layout, any idea?

Comment: which on of the views broke? you mean for service? do you have the action `service` in your services_controller?

Comment: sorry, I mean, when I go to path /companies/1/services, I don't get any layout as I get with /companies/1. So the 'index' for services is showing all by itself. I had a layout for companies which does not seem to be linked to services.

Comment: That's weird... just check what is in your assets folder. Sometimes rails create some layout with the scaffolder. If so, try deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you a  ServicesController class?

You should do this :

```
resources :companies do
  resources :services do
    member do
      get 'service'
    end
  end
end
```